# Return more than one variable from a Java method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

> - Your program must read the id number and gpa and transfer the data into two separate arrays.  You can assume there will never be more than 1000 students in the file.  Do you know why you must use two separate arrays?  You may find it useful in this program to create additional arrays to complete the requirements of the program as described next.
> - Your program must do two distinctly different things correctly for full credit:
>     You must create a simple diagram to show how many students fall into each of 8 different categories.  This type of diagram is known as a histogram and it is generally useful to show how data is distributed across a range.
> - For each student in the input file, you must display their S-number, gpa, and class rank.  The S-number and gpa will already be in your arrays; however, you must calculate their class rank.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner gpadata;
    String snum;
    double gpa;
    int groupNumber;

    gpadata = new Scanner(new File("studentdata.txt"));

    while (gpadata.hasNext())
    {
        snum = gpadata.next();
        gpa = gpadata.nextDouble();
        groupNumber = gpaGroup(gpa);

        System.out.println("Student number, GPA, and group number"
                + " is: " + snum +
                "    " + gpa + "    " + groupNumber);  


    }
}


//Method to categorize students GPA into 1 of 8 groups
public static int gpaGroup(double gpa)
{

    //Declare all variables
    int gpaGroup;


    //Assign GPA a group number
    if (gpa >= 0.0 && gpa < 0.5)
        gpaGroup = 1;
    else if (gpa >= 0.5 && gpa < 1.0)
        gpaGroup = 2;
    else if (gpa >= 1.0 && gpa < 1.5)
        gpaGroup = 3;
    else if (gpa >= 1.5 && gpa < 2.0)
        gpaGroup = 3;
    else if (gpa >= 2.0 && gpa < 2.5)
        gpaGroup = 4;
    else if (gpa >= 2.5 && gpa < 3.0)
        gpaGroup = 5;
    else if (gpa >= 3.0 && gpa < 3.5)
        gpaGroup = 6;
    else
        gpaGroup = 7;

    //Return int value of group number
    return gpaGroup;
}

//Method to find number of students in each group
public static void studentsInGroup(int gpaGroup)
{
    //Declare all variables
    int gpaGroup1 = 0;
    int gpaGroup2 = 0;
    int gpaGroup3 = 0;
    int gpaGroup4 = 0;
    int gpaGroup5 = 0;
    int gpaGroup6 = 0;
    int gpaGroup7 = 0;
    int gpaGroup8 = 0;

    //Total students in each GPA group
    if (gpaGroup == 1)
        gpaGroup1++;
    else if (gpaGroup == 2)
        gpaGroup2++;
    else if (gpaGroup == 3)
        gpaGroup3++;
    else if (gpaGroup == 4)
        gpaGroup4++;
    else if (gpaGroup == 5)
        gpaGroup5++;
    else if (gpaGroup == 6)
        gpaGroup6++;
    else if (gpaGroup == 7)
        gpaGroup7++;
    else
        gpaGroup8++;

}
```

Can I modify my method to return more than one variable from a method (in `public static void studentsInGroup(int gpaGroup)` return values of number of students in each group)? Is this where arrays start to come in? From here I would write another method to round number of students in each category to the nearest ten, then use this to write a method for creating a histogram etc etc.

I have been trying my hardest to understand the concepts, but I have been struggling lately. This is one of my last assignments for the semester and I'd like to keep my A, and also understand what I'm doing.

Comment: *Is this where arrays start to come in?* I assume, when you have a list of variables of the same type like you do above with gpa groups, consider using an array. Also, if you need to get all group numbers at one time, yes, you'd need an array or collection of some sort.

Comment: Create a new class, put your _variables_ in it and return a new instance of that class. If its the same type, consider a `Collection` or an array instead.

Comment: I can't see why you'd create a class to hold an array, but that's also an over complicated option.

Comment: are you able to share real or sample data from the file you are reading? from the 1st line in the file.

Comment: @Searching Example: "S4940364   2.62"    The first is a student number and the second is a GPA

Answer (score 0):

Can I modify my method to return more than one variable from a method (in public static void studentsInGroup(int gpaGroup) return values of number of students in each group)?

Yes, you can. You can create an object that contains two variables. However, the instructions suggest a different solution.

Inside your loop, read the id and gpa, and immediately stick them in two separate arrays.

Here is a fragment:

```
snums = [];
gpas = [];
while (gpadata.hasNext())
{
    snum = gpadata.next();
    gpa = gpadata.nextDouble();
    snums.append(snum);
    gpas.append(gpa);
}
```

Comment: Alright, you're 100% right; however I am confused as to how I am supposed to stick this information into 2 separate arrays. I know the syntax for creating an array is: elementType[] arrayRefVar = new elementType[arraySize] but I don't understand how you passed the read information into each array

Comment: snums.append(snum) adds one element to the array. Once everyone is in array, you can iterate over it, and print it out. You are expert at making easy things hard. You

Answer (score 0):

ensure you are doing the following. I'm not giving away any code here. Also not sure why they want you to use `array` only!?!

Breakdown your requirement and see what you need to achieve.

1. Start with reading each line from file
2. each line is separated by " " and has id_number and gpa
3. from the requirement, the file will not contain more than 1000 students(1000 lines). You may declare this as a static class level variable `static String[] idnum_array = new String[1000];` and another array for gpa which is `Double[]`
4. read each line and then separate by using `String.split(" ")` method. The first variable is your id number and 2nd will be your gpa. you follow ?
5. maintain a separate counter to increment the array position each time you set these values in the two arrays you created in step 3.

   ```
   Integer i = 0;
   while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = scanner.nextLine();
       String[] splitString = line.split(" ");
       idnum_array[i] = String.valueOf(splitString[0]);
       gpa_array[i] = Double.valueOf(splitString[1]);
       i++;
   }
   ```

Do you agree that if we do `idnum_array[7]` to return it's corresponding gpa result from `gpa_array[7]` for that student ?

How you choose to count the number of people in a certain group is upto you.
I would do the following

1. create a static class level variable `static Integer[] group_array = new Integer[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // there are only 8 groups!`
2. loop my `gpa_array`
3. have an if/else inside the loop to check which group it falls in
4. increment the value at that index by 1. `group_array[index]++;`

In the end I will have an array of 8 elements which will correspond to the 8 groups. `[0,200,300,200,0,300,0,0,0]`

You should end up with nearly 4 methods similar to this.
1. readDataFromFile(String fileName)
2. groupGPAIntoCategory()
3. drawHistogram()
4. calculateRank()

I would personally create a `Student` object from the very beginning. 
It's just cleaner and readable. Make sure you have your `try catch` block to print your exceptions and always comment!